# Primefaces Dialog Framework - Open dialog - close it - open another dialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

**Primefaces 5.0, JSF 2.2, Wildfly 8.1**

The following use case:

1. Click a command button in a view (with some parameters)
2. The bean method looks something up in the database - if necessary *dialog1* is shown. In *dialog1* there is a form and a command button.
3. The command button in *dialog1* is clicked, the bean method looks something up in the database.
4. *Dialog1* is closed and *dialog2*, depending on the result of the bean method, is shown.

**bean1.java:**

```
public void buttonClicked() {

    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("widgetVar", "dialog1");
    options.put("id", "dlg1");

if(somethingTrue()) {
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("dialog1.xhtml", options, null);
    }
}
```

Everything fine. Dialog1 shows up.

**dialog1.xhtml:**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Button" actionListener="#{bean2.dialog1ButtonClicked}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**bean2.java:**

```
public void dialog1ButtonClicked() {        
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("widgetVar", "dialog2");
    options.put("id", "dlg2");    

if(somethingTrue()) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("dialog2.xhtml", options, null);
    }
}
```

**dialog2.xhtml:**

```
<h:body>        
    The operation was successful.
</h:body>
```

*Dialog2 shows up within dialog1!*

### **How can I close dialog1 and show dialog2 NOT within dialog1?**

I tried closing dialog1 with Primefaces Dialog Framework before opening dialog2:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null);
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("dialog2.xhtml", options, null);
```

Dialog2 doesn't show up.

I tried opening dialog2 after the AJAX callback `<p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{bean1.dialogClosed}"/>`
Dialog2 doesn't show.

I tried the client side Java Script call: `onclick="PF('dialog1').hide()"`

Dialog2 still shows up nested into dialog1.

Comment: Why are you opening the dialog with first argument "dialog2.xhtml" and not just "dialog2" as in the showcase?

Comment: You can try to close/show the dialog on server side with `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogWidVar').show()")` or `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogWidVar').close()")`

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar: Both ways result in the same. I just used the filename to avoid a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

- Open just one dialog:
  `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("dialog1.xhtml", options, null);`

  - The dialog flow is controlled by an ajax update of the main panel, where the rendered attribute is bound to a bean property and therefore completely controlled by the bean.

*dialog1.xhtml:*

```
<p:dialog class="userRegisterDialog" header="#{bean.dailogHeader}" 
                          modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false">

    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{bean2.closeRegistration}" update=":update"/>

    <p:panel id="update">
        <p:panel id="step1" rendered="#{bean.showStep1}">
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton class="continueButton" value="Button1" actionListener="#{bean.doStep1}" update=":update"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:panel>
        <p:panel id="step2" rendered="#{bean.showStep2}">                        
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton class="closeButton" value="Button2" actionListener="#{bean.doStep2}" update=":update"/>
            </h:form>               
        </p:panel>
    </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

The dialog bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable 
    {

    private boolean showStep1 = true;
    private boolean showStep2 = false;

    public void doStep1(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        if(doSomething())
        {
            setShowStep1(false);            
            setShowStep2(true);
        }
    }            

    public void doStep2(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        if(doSomething2())
        {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(null);
        }
    }

    // Getter and setter ...    
}
```

Another bean for the dialog closing:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean2 implements Serializable {
    public void closeRegistration() { 
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove("bean");
    }    
}
```

The method *closeRegistration* removes the viewscoped bean. Therefore another call of the the dialog within the same page will start the dialog flow from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

using `onHide` you can open another dialog like this.

```
<p:dialog class="userRegisterDialog" header="#{bean.dailogHeader}" modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false" onHide="PF('dialog2').show();>
</p:dialog>
```

It also work when close dialog using escape key.

Comment: But with this solution you've got no decision path!

Comment: what you mean `you've got no decision path!` ? @Chris

Comment: The question was, to show different dialogs depending on the outcome of a server side method.

Comment: so you server side write like this `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialog1').hide();PF('dialog2').show()");`

Comment: Have you tried this? Because I think I tried this, and it didn't work. The dialogs still have been nested.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

we can close on dialog in `onsuccess` or `onerror` or `oncomplete` also. Check the image for your reference

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.